# Centering a child in a parent narrower than itself

Tags: html, css

So I've come up with a way to center children in a parent that is smaller than itself.  I'm not to keen on the extra markup it takes to accomplish, and I am wondering if there is a better way to accomplish this, with better meaning less extra markup/styling, or "cleaner" in general.

#### THE GOAL

Given a parent that is smaller (less wide), put the center of the child element in the center of the parent element dynamically without knowing the width of the child element or the parent element.

#### MY APPROACH

So my approach uses three nested spans (the element itself is of little consequence).

The first span has a `width` of `0px` and is centered via `margin: 0 auto`. This gives us the center of the parent container.

The second span has a `width` of `auto`, a `white-space` of `nowrap`, and a `display` of `inline-block`.  The `display` is the key here. This restores the natural width of the child element

the third span has a `position` of relative, and a `left` of `-50%`. This centers the span in relation to the parent by offsetting half of the width of the child in relation to the center of the parent.

#### THE QUESTION

Is there a cleaner/less "janky" way of doing this?

#### THE MARKUP

```
<div class="box">
  <span class="first-wrap">
    <span class="second-wrap">
      <span class="third-wrap">
         This should be centered in relation to the box;
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

### THE STYLES

```
.box { 
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  margin: 40px auto;
}

.box .first-wrap {
  display: block;
  width: 0px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.box .first-wrap .second-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.box .first-wrap .second-wrap .third-wrap {
  position: relative;
  left: -50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

#### THE FIDDLE

https://jsfiddle.net/d3w1wom0/

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets along with your question as codes in external links might expire or get deleted thus rendering this question useless for other people having the same issue in the long run.

Comment: why did this get voted down? I'd like to avoid future mistakes.

Comment: The downvote was for the lack of code snippets. I have removed the downvote now. Cheers

Comment: How does the answer you accepted at the moment achieves your goal of parent narrower than children?

Comment: because it does in fact center a child in a parent that is narrower than the child.  Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d3w1wom0/1/

Comment: With one child it looks fine, but in your example you have three, my understanding is that they should stay in the same line and all centered.

Comment: just need A child to be centered. Sorry for the confusion. If you need them to do what you are saying, you can update the flex-direction to column.

Comment: Anyway you have it, switch to column will not make them to stay in the same line.

Comment: change the markup so they are siblings and it will: https://jsfiddle.net/d3w1wom0/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete your css and replace with the following:

```
.box {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

If you want to change the width, and center things accordingly you can just add the following to the above .box class:

```
width: 60%;
margin: 0 auto;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.box {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 20px;
}
```

will center your text in the box